# coloring specific areas on an image

Tags: javascript, image, colors, area

I'm currently working on website allowing users to select colors from input, that will then be affected on a specific area of an image.

Here is an image example :[image]

**Result example** : If the user selected red color, the 1 zone will be colored red and so on.
Is there a way to do it directly on the image with JavaScript/CSS, or I have to use canvas component? Otherwise, if there is already an existing tool allowing to achieve this?

I found this fun tool, but they are using geoJSON standard : https://www.amcharts.com/demos/selecting-multiple-areas-map/

So, must I have to generate by myself a geoJSON format to work directly on, or it's possible to work directly on an image?
If you have any ideas, I'm interested!

Comment: You may want to checkout [these examples](https://datamaps.github.io/) build on top of [D3.js](https://d3js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You could work with the image by splitting it into the areas you need, but this is not the way I would do it.

You could use an SVG and put it above the image inside the SVG you could define areas and just hide/show them when needed.

But if you find some library that automatically does things for you that might be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

An open-source library like [HTML5-Paint-Bucket-Tool](https://github.com/williammalone/HTML5-Paint-Bucket-Tool) can help you bucket fill color into a bit map image. The downside is that you do not know which zone is colored what since it's just an image.

For vectors or SVG, state controls are easier but to display and render a map will require a lot more effort.